# pyspark job fails while printing show(n)

Tags: python, pyspark

I am running a pyspark job with a large number of transformations. At some point in the code as a part of debugging, I use `print(df.count())` to trigger an action, so that I could debug the transformations so far.

But when I give a `print(df.show(5))`, it gives me a n error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
> Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 21437"...

Why does that happen, If the code can print the count of the rows successfully what is preventing it from printing the data?

Comment: The error indicates you are running out of space on your executor(s) , you can further read this - https://luminousmen.com/post/dive-into-spark-memory and arguments you can use to deal with this

Comment: @Vaebhav But why does it works for count() and not on the show()? it should fail on both right?

Comment: count is not a computationally heavy process , are there any other transforms in between count & print

Comment: No, I just gave both of them in line after line, ie; count() first then on the next line show(5). In the output, the count is being printed, but show() is not shown.